# nestJS class-validator: change requirement of property based on another property

Tags: node.js, nestjs, class-validator

Let's say I have a DTO with a category property:

```
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsEnum(Category)
  category: Category;
```

and then I have some other property

```
   @ApiProperty()
   @IsString()
   @MaxLength(1000)
   name: string
```

And what I want to do is change the max length number of name conditionally depending on what category is chosen - if it's "x" then it should be 500, if it's "y" then 700 etc. Is it something I could do easily?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a work-around by using groups in `ValidatorOptions`

```
import { MaxLength, MinLength, IsString} from "class-validator";

export class User {
    @MaxLength(500, {groups: ["x"]})
    @MinLength(1000, {groups: ["y"]})
    // or specify min,max length 
    // Length(2, 500, { groups: ["x"]})
    // Length(2, 1000, { groups: ["y"]})
    @IsString()
    name: string;
}
```

And, when you instantiate an entity, you can specify a group like this.

```
User user = new User()
user.name = 'name'
validate(user, groups: ["x"])
```